# How to wrap around values (using `mod`) when using get/set for array values?

Tags: c#, arrays, getter, setter

NOTICE: I do not want do wrap the index of the array, in fact, I already did that. I also want to [wrap the individual values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415753/wrap-value-into-range-min-max-without-division) of the array when they are set.

I am trying to get array values to automatically wrap around without using a for loop to do it, because I have a fairly large array (uint16 limit).

I was trying to use a get/set and use a simple wrap code if it is above the max or below the minimum.

Is there any way I can do this?

What I want:

`MyArray[0] = 5`

`//MyArray's max is 3, and minimum is 0`

Outcome:
`MyArray[0] = 2`

---

The problem is not [looping around indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894948/make-an-array-work-like-a-circle), but instead to have the values reduced to a limited range.

I've seen how to implement indexer - like [Example of Indexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786526/example-of-indexer) and how to clamp value - [Where can I find the "clamp" function in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683442/where-can-i-find-the-clamp-function-in-net) (some even were suggested as duplicates).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that works on the indexes. OP wants the values mod 5

Comment: i think you will have to create a wrapper around an array and overload the indexer function

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I will, give me a moment..

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov no problem, I just want to solve this as quick as possible and I'm willing to do whatever it takes.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it´s also clearly not about clamping as a value of 5 would be converted to 2.

Comment: https://ideone.com/h181Pi

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Actually, I'm using my own set method to wrap them! I am currently integrating these answers now, and although I do believe it is a bit hacky, it will work. Thanks for your concern!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this help?

```
using System;
public class ModArray
{
    int [] _array;
    int _mod;
    public ModArray(int size, int mod){
        _array = new int[size];
        _mod = mod;
    }
    public int this[int index]
    {
        get => _array[index];
        set => _array[index] = value % _mod;
    }
}
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ma = new ModArray(10,3);
        ma[0] = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(ma[0]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the way you set the values, you can just use the `remainder` operator (it should be like `MyArray[0] = 5 % 3`).

But if you can't, you will have to wrap your array in a class (as you cannot subclass arrays) similar to this:

```cs
class MyArray
{
   // Declare an array to store the data elements.
   private uint16[] arr = new uint16[100];

   // Define the indexer to allow client code to use [] notation.
   public uint16 this[int i]
   {
      get { return arr[i]; }
      set { arr[i] = value % 5; }
   }
}
```